# Clone or deploy bot translation

Tags: translation, translation-workbench, bots, einstein-bots

I am using Salesforce bots.

I use translations, and I have added translations for all my bot dialogs and messages, for German, Spanish and French languages.

Now I want to clone the bot into a new version to update it.

Problem is: the translations are not copied with the clone command into the new version.

I have opened a case to Salesforce and got an answer:

> we have found a Bug lodged for this issue with the R&D Teams- "W-11367773"...

So I am waiting, but who knows when this will be fixed

I have also tried to deploy this bot and bot version and translations with `sfdx.exe`, the problem is that in the translation file, each dialog and message have their own `stepIdentifier` and `messageIdentifier` and this identifier is different for each version since I have cloned it. so this is also not possible for copying the translations.

**Question:**

Any possible way to clone / copy / deploy translations of the bots into new versions / production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W-11367773 is marked fixed and I *believe* was included in Summer '22 Patch 11 which *should* be in your org. You can check what patch your instance is on with the [trust site](https://status.salesforce.com/).

As such, cloning new versions as you did *should* include translations which will help you in deploying. If they do not, and you're on a patch number for Summer '22 greater than 11, I would suggest following up on that case (or creating a new one).

To be specific, the issue was the *number* of translations for the version as it always attempted to include translations. The fix was related to handling larger number of translations in the clone process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kris, currently my org is running with `Summer '22 Patch 11.2`. How can I access W-11367773 to see it?

Comment: You can't access W-11367773 as that is a work item story for internal Salesforce. What you can try again is cloning your bot to a new version to check that the translations are now included.

Comment: actually we have tested this again, and it does work now - cloning and also deploying the new version with its translation. thanks for all the help!

Comment: I still have a problem with deploying translations, it looks like the translatation I get with the sfdx command is getting **only** the `<type>Message</type>` from each `<botSteps>` so all the other types are not getting deployed. do you know of this?

Comment: I see an internal work item to fix this bug (no public facing knowledge article). Did you create a case? Might make more sense to create a separate question on here too.

Comment: yes, I did open a case, it looks like deploying bot translation is not supported - eventually the support guy pointed me to use the Translation Workbench->Import/Export tool, which works, but is really bad and outside of my SDLC process.
Anyway - I think this should work